# Determining percentages and past seven days

Tags: php, math

I am coming here with a fairly simple (i think) question today. I would like to figure out the past seven days with php

So: I have todays date in variables (like `$day = 2, $month = 5, $year = 2013`, all put together 2/5/2013), My question is How would i go about getting the past seven days (in the same format) such as in this case

```
2/5/2013
1/5/2013
30/4/2013
29/4/2013
28/4/2013
27/4/2013
26/4/2013
```

I have tried subtracting the days for each variable (like `$day6 = $todays_date - 1;`) but getting month and year changes from that would be quite difficult i believe.

any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mktime, and subtract the number of seconds for each day:

```
$today = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++){
    echo date('j/n/Y',$today-($i*(24*60*60))) . '<br />;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php) and its [modify method](http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.modify.php)

```
$date = new DateTime();
$yesterday = $date->modify('-1 day');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$day = '02/05/2013';

$dates = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . ' -' . $i . 'days'));
}

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($dates);
die();
```